# Alternating grid colours

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, css-selectors

I'm wanting to achieve a two column grid layout that has grid blocks with alternating colours. However, achieving this with a simple nth-child(odd) or nth-child(even)won't do the trick.

I'm pretty sure what I want can be achieved using a touch of nth-child trickery, rather than a JS solution, but not quite sure how.

Here's a pen of what I'm wanting to achieve: http://codepen.io/abbasinho/pen/Gbnze

Here's the HTML as it is in the pen, i'd like to avoid the additional class to add the colors:

```
<div class="grid-holder">
  <div class="grid red"></div>
  <div class="grid blue"></div>
  <div class="grid blue"></div>
  <div class="grid red"></div>
  <div class="grid red"></div>
  <div class="grid blue"></div>
  <div class="grid blue"></div>
  <div class="grid red"></div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
.grid-holder {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;

    &.red {
      background: red;
    }

    &.blue {
      background: blue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you repeat a pattern every 4 elements (red/blue/blue/red), you can achieve this with `:nth-child(4n+x)` variations :

```
<div class="grid-holder">

  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>

</div>
```

```
.grid-holder {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: red;

    // The 2nd and the 3rd element in our pattern will be blue
    &:nth-child(4n+2),
    &:nth-child(4n+3) {
        background: blue;
    }  
}
```